# Setting PATH variable in XFCE4

Tags: linux, debian, path, xfce4

I have some programs installed in my `~/.local/bin/` folder and in `/etc/profile` I've got the following:

```
if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
else
  PATH="~/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:~/.cabal/bin"
fi
export PATH
```

XFCE4 does not respect this variable, instead having `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games` as PATH, so if I open xfce4-terminal I cannot start programs located in `~/.local/bin/`. This also goes for emacs if started from XFCE4, so `M-x run-shen`, for instance, does not work, as shen is not installed system-wide.

This problem does not occur when using `startx`, so the problem probably is with how XFCE4 is started.

I did `grep -R PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games /etc/`, but that didn't turn up anything but `/etc/login.def`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct file to use is `~/.xsessionrc`.

Just create that file and enter:

```
PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH:~/.cabal/bin
export PATH
```

Comment: Doesn't work with XFCE 4.12 on Ubuntu 16.04 running in vncserver.

Comment: @FlorinAndrei Maybe try the solution provided by Gilles Quenot below?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is this :

```
cp /etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc  ~/.config/xfce4/xinitrc
```

then edit `~/.config/xfce4/xinitrc` to put

```
export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH:~/.cabal/bin
```

Comment: There are two answers. They both look reasonable. Is this one correct or the other!? Are they both viable alternatives? Does this one replace the other answer (regarding `~/.xsessionrc`)?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281858/difference-between-xinitrc-xsession-and-xsessionrc Contain a bit more details, but essentially, it seems like `xinitrc` is the most "portable" choice, but either solution should work.

Answer (score 0):

If it's running under a vncserver, check `PATH` variable has not been set in `.vnc/xstartup`, otherwise it will override the the one set in `.profile` or `/etc/environment`.