# Why is PATH defined in ~/.profile even though launching a Terminal with bash executes only ~/.bashrc?

Tags: bash, .profile

I have a `guest` user account on my Debian system with XFCE desktop.

It has a `~/.profile` file added by default. The last few lines of this
file are:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

echo .profile executed
```

The last `echo` command is added by me. I have ensured that `$HOME/bin` exists.

```
guest@debian:~$ ls -ld $HOME/bin
drwxr-xr-x 2 guest guest 4096 Jan  9 09:42 /home/guest/bin
```

After booting my Debian system, I log into my XFCE desktop using the
`guest` account and launch Terminal (xfce4-terminal). But I do not see
any evidence that `~/.profile` was executed.

```
guest@debian:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

`man bash` makes it pretty clear that `~/.profile` is read and executed in an interactive login shell or a non-interactive shell with the `--login` option. `~/.bashrc` is executed in interactive non-login shell, so it seems alright that when xfce4-terminal launches bash, `~/.profile` is not executed.

If `~/.profile` is not executed when we launch a new Terminal, why is
the `PATH` updated in `~/.profile`?

Shouldn't Debian provide the `PATH` update in `~/.bashrc` so that it is
available to the user when the user launches a terminal?

Comment: [This article](https://blog.flowblok.id.au/2013-02/shell-startup-scripts.html) explains nicely which startup script is run when.

Comment: What do you mean by *"the PATH updated in ~/.profile"*?

Comment: @EmilyE. See the first code block in my question. It updates the existing (inherited) `PATH` by adding `$HOME/bin` to the beginning of the `PATH`.

Comment: Basically .profile is (intended to be) sourced once per *login* session. If you login from a terminal you'll see your echo. In a X session it's simulated - something else will source that file to emulated legacy behavior (once for your session). When you launch a terminal from within XFCE your not logging in again, your just forking some process. Also for better "evidence" why don't you do ~ "echo .profile executed \`date\` >> /tmp/profile-hits".

Comment: @spinkus I added that line to my `~/.profile`, rebooted my system, logged into XFCE, and launched a terminal. But `/tmp/profile-hits` was not created confirming my claim that `~/.profile` was not executed at any stage. I know if I log into a real terminal (`tty1`, `tty2`, etc.), `~/.profile` is going to get executed. However, I am interested to know why the `PATH` is redefined in `~/.profile` when this redefinition is not going to affect any terminal session within the XFCE desktop environment.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [SU].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man bash`:

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a
>   non-interactive shell with the −−login option, it first reads and
>   executes commands from the file **/etc/profile**, if that file exists.
>   After reading that file, it looks for **~/.bash_profile**, **~/.bash_login**,
>   and **~/.profile**, in that order, and reads and executes commands from
>   the first one that exists and is readable....
>
> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash
>   reads and executes commands from **~/.bashrc**, if that file exists....

I understand that

1. `~/.bashrc`:  for interactive shell
2. `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile`: for login shell

So, if you need to modify `PATH` in Terminal, which is an interactive shell, then you might want to put that `PATH` settings in `~/.bashrc`; or, alternatively, you can source `~/.profile` from `~/.bashrc` whenever you are in non-login shell, example:

```
shopt -q login_shell || . ~/.profile
```

**As for why `PATH` is set in `~/.profile` as a recommended way**, I believe that user's defined `PATH` should be set right when he/she logins, and "login" can be `bash`, `zsh`, or GUI, or somewhat else.

**Senario 1:** Some user might want non-X as the default working environment; and X is called by running `startx` normally or automatically from `~/.profile` when the login virtual terminal is `tty7`.

```
[ -z $DISPLAY -a $XDG_VTNR -eq 7 ] && exec startx
```

In this case, users chose carefully what to set in `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc`, and `~/.xinitrc`, so that they have the desired set of enviroment variables ---`PATH`, `EDITOR`, `VISUAL`, `BROWSER`, etc.--- whether he/she is working in:

1. Consoles (Ctrl+Alt+F[1-6]), or logging in without X via `ssh`: `~/.profile` + `~/.bashrc`
2. Non terminal progams in X: `~/.profile` + `~/.xinitrc`
3. Terminal emulators in X: `~/.profile` + `~/.xinitrc` + `~/.bashrc`

So, setting `PATH` in `~/.profile` is the best choice. Users can set `EDITOR` as `vim` in `~/.profile` (in non-X), but change it to `emacs` in `~/.xinitrc` (in X).

**Senario 2:** A GUI user who logins to `XFCE` instead login as `bash`; so `PATH` could be set in `~/.xsessionrc` as [explained here](https://superuser.com/questions/990860/setting-path-variable-in-xfce4).

**Senario 3:** A `zsh` user can set `PATH` in `~/.zprofile`. Interactive settings for `bash` are places in `~/.bashrc`, and interactive settings for `zsh` are placed in `~/.zshrc`.

Answer (score 0):

`~/.profile` is executed when you log in using the console mode and not the gui mode. You can use keys `F1, F2 ...` to log in using console mode.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. `~/.profile` is executed in an interactive login shell well as a non-interactive shell with the `--login` option. It has nothing to do with whether the shell is launched in tty or GUI. Even in GUI, you can launch an interactive login shell with the `su -` command and `~/.profile` would be executed. See `man bash` for more details.

Having said that, what is your answer to the actual question asked: Why is `PATH` defined in `~/.profile` if it is not going to be available in an interactive non-login shell?

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. I just went through [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/279374). It raises a similar question. I personally don't have an answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

`Edit -> Profile Preferences -> Title and Command -> "Run command as a login shell"`

The usual `~/.profile` loads `~/.bashrc` if it is available, if - assuming `$BASH_VERSION` is present in your environment.

Keep in mind though that `~/.profile` is ignored if if there's `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` in your home and that, as a result of it being ignored, `~/.bashrc` isn't sourced, too.

This answer was sourced from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/155223/170676) while researching a similar issue.
And [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88108/170676) answer from Unix & Linux mentions how Debian handles shell configs with links that may help.

Comment: In recent-ish Debian default files, `.profile` checks if it's running Bash, and if so, loads `.bashrc`. In the glacial terms of Debian development, this is a relatively recent arrangement, and certainly not generalizable to other distributions.

Comment: @Yokai So why does Debian define a custom `PATH` in `~/.profile` even though it is not going to be executed at all by default when we launch Bash in XFCE Terminal?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding has always been that `.bashrc` is specific for bash and `.profile` is cross-shell. This may not be an issue for most of the home users, but I am sometimes on a system where users prefer `ksh` (and enforce that choice on new users). If for some reason you get a bournshell, `.profile` is also used. Note that zsh and csh do not use .profile.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused. Which part of my question are you answering?

Comment: If ~/.profile is not executed when we launch a new Terminal, why is the PATH updated in ~/.profile?